# Mover un elemento dentro de otro SCSS

Tags: sass, scss

Tengo una página web y estoy intentando mover un elemento link "a" dentro de un "div" ya existente. El código generado sería algo así:

```
<a href="google.es" class="download-link">Download file</a>
<form>
  ...
  </form>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

La idea es mover el link dentro de la clase "footer" mediante SCSS. Soy un novato en el maquetado y no consigo encontrar la forma. Supongo que podría hacerlo mediante el backend de la página, pero eso lo dejo como último recurso. Muchas a gracias a todos.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a moverlo a nivel visual o a nivel de código? Es decir, que visualmente el `a` ocupe el mismo lugar que el `div` o que el código se transforme a `<div><a></a></div>` (Esto último CREO que no se puede hacer con scss, tendrías que usar JavaScript/JQuery para hacerlo desde el cliente si quieres evitar el backend)

Answer (score 0):

Solo con css, o scss en tu caso podrías hacer algo así, de esta manera puedes conseguir que el enlace se vea dentro del footer:

```css
.footer {border:1px solid black;width:100%;height:100px;}
.download-link {position:absolute;top:20%;}
```

```html
<a href="google.es" class="download-link" id="link">Download file</a>
<form>
  ...
  </form>
<div class="footer" id="footer"></div>
```

Pero yo te recomiendo hacerlo con javascript para no tener que forzar el posicionamiento de los elementos, con js es mucho más fácil y aconsejable, tendrías que hacer que el enlace sea hijo del footer, aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```js
document.getElementById("footer").appendChild(document.getElementById("link"));
```

```css
.footer {border:1px solid black;width:100%;height:100px;}
```

```html
<a href="google.es" class="download-link" id="link">Download file</a>
<form>
  ...
  </form>
<div class="footer" id="footer"></div>
```